# Django: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a form in Django which would include a form field with a default value extracted from the `User` object.

forms.py

```
class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #full_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Full Name")
    email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email ID")
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(help_text="Mobile number")
    twitter_url = forms.CharField(help_text="Twitter URL")
```

models.py

```
class Evangelized(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{10}$', message='Mobile number should be strictly of 10 digits.')])
    twitter_url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
```

views.py

```
def fillform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        #form = EvangelizedForm()
        form = EvangelizedForm(initial={'full_name': request.get_full_name()})

    context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user, 'form':form})    

    #return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form, 'context_instance':context})  
    return render_to_response('rango/fillform.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'
```

What does this error signify, and how do I resolve this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you want:

```
request.user.get_full_name() if request.user.is_authenticated() else ""
```

Comment: Note - in 2020 i belive it's just request.user.is_authenticated without the ()

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I do not get your point. Please elaborate.